# Custom pagination for displaying a merged array in Drupal 7

Tags: pagination, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have implemented a search functionality in my site in Drupal 7 with views. I have a custom template for this view, in which I am displaying the merged array using views_query_alter. So if I apply pagination for the views, it goes wrong. It paginates the result from the view, not the result which I have customised.

I need to implement pagination for displaying this merged array in the view template. Any solution for this will be really helpful..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the view module, you can set the pagination on the  view configuration page. You can set how result you want by page.

Comment: I am not displaying the views result as such.In the views template, if I use default pagination of views, it shows wrong result, like only rows under that particular view is shown and some of the row results is hidden(extra results which I am passing through merged array). So I need help for adding custom pagination in views to paginate the whole array results.

Comment: I think it's more easy and efficient to understand why drupal view give you a wrong result